# How to insert text inside \cite

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am citing a bunch of authors that support a certain statement, but would like to acknowledge an important paper that denies it. So I want the text to look like this:

> A large percentage of South American biodiversity originated during the Quaternary period, a period with intense climatic changes which deeply affected vegetation dynamics and species diversification in the continent [Mayle, 2004; Carnaval et al, 2009; Werneck, 2011; Collevatti et al, 2012; Werneck et al, 2012; Ledo and Colli, 2017; Costa et al, 2018; but see Melo et al, 2016].

How do I insert the phrase "but see" there before the last reference?

Comment: I wouldn't do it at all. If it is important to note, give it a sentence of its own.

Comment: If and how that is possible depends on which packages you use to generate your citations/bibliography (no package at all, i.e. the standard kernel definition, `cite`, `natbib`, `biblatex`, ...). It would be a great help if you could show us a small example document with a citation that demonstrates which citation packages you load and use. For `biblatex` one would use `\cites` here: `\cites{mayle}{carnaval}[but see][]{melo}`. ...

Comment: ... I should add that people may not always read the citations as closely as the rest of the text and a 'but see also' might simply get lost among the other text in the brackets, so if it is important to make the point it might be wise to mention the dissenting opinions in the text directly and explicitly.